# placeholder in wordpress mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How do I correctly put a variable in a mysql statement for wordpress?

I tried `date = %d`, but it isn't working, should I just do `date='$date'`:

```
  $date = $v_date->DATE; 
  $count = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    " SELECT DISTINCT `date`,
    (select subscriber_count FROM wp_email_signup where LIST_NAME = 'B' AND date = %d) as 'B',
    (select subscriber_count FROM wp_email_signup where LIST_NAME = '2D' AND date = %d ) as 'D',
    (select subscriber_count FROM wp_email_signup where LIST_NAME = 'F' AND date = %d ) as 'F'
        FROM wp_email_signup WHERE date = %d", $date));
```

Comment: Try `date = %1d` instead `date = %d` for each placeholder.

Comment: that doesn't work. Why should it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your date is not an integer, that's why it was not working.

The query parameter for prepare accepts sprintf()-like placeholders.

%s (string)

%d (integer)

%f (float)

formats are supported. (The %s and %d placeholders have been available since the function was added to core in Version 2.3, %f has only been available since Version 3.3.) Any other % characters may cause parsing errors unless they are escaped.

All % characters inside SQL string literals, including LIKE wildcards, must be double-% escaped as %%. All of %d, %f, and %s are to be left unquoted in the query string.

**Note that the %d placeholder only accepts integers, so you can't pass numbers that have comma values via %d.** If you need comma values, use %f as float instead.

for More https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders

Comment: I replaced %d with %f and it still doesn't work. date='$date' works fine. Is it ok to use it?

Comment: Ltech, your date is string if date format is '2015-04-05' and mysql takes dates as string.  so %f and $d will not work , please use %s.